# Problem integrating firebase sdk with ruby app. No documentation found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, sdk

I'm trying to send push notifications using **Firebase cloud messaging** but I'm having issue adding firebase SDK and initializing app. I've searched almost everything about this but there's no documentation for integrating **Firebase SDK** with **Ruby**.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

I've searched almost everything about this but there's no documentation for integrating **Firebase SDK** with **Ruby**.

Comment: There is no official Firebase Admin SDK for Ruby, so you would just have to use FCM HTTP API. This is not _that_ complicated (just follow the documentation), but there are gems (I thing even several ones) that wrap this API into some Ruby(-ish) interface...

Comment: Sounds like an answer @KonstantinStrukov :)